# Looping through multiple date records to find the number of days

Tags: sql, function, loops, ms-access, vba

need to loop through date records in order to calculate the number of days worked. The number of dates varies from each person, they could have as few as one or as many as 11, ending with a calculation from the last dat in the sequence to the current days date.

Example of Data:

```
Employee No     Date     
4522            08/11/2011
4522            09/06/2011
4522            05/04/2013
4522            07/15/2013
4522            01/31/2014
```

So today is 04/29/2014, so from 01/31/2014 to 04/29/2014 is 88 days, 05/04/2013 to 07/15/2013 is 72 days and 08/11/2011 to 09/06/2011 is 26 days. Add those all together and you get a total of 186 days worked.

Again the number of dates will vary in each case.

Here's what I have so far...

```
Sub getActualEmployment(empID As Variant)
  Dim strconnection, strSQL As String
  Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
  Dim tbl As ADODB.Recordset
  Dim OptimumCode As String
  Dim orghrdt As Date
  Dim intNumDays As Integer

  strSQL = "SELECT EmployeeID,EffectiveDate, OriginalHireDate FROM "
  strSQL = strSQL & "EmploymentStatusChanges WHERE EmployeeID= '" & empID & "'"
  strSQL = strSQL & " Order by EffectiveDate ASC"

  Set tbl = New ADODB.Recordset

  With tbl
    Set .ActiveConnection = conn
    .Source = strSQL
    .LockType = adLockOptimistic
    .CursorType = adOpenKeyset
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .Open
  End With

  With tbl
    On Error Resume Next
    .MoveFirst
      Do Until tbl.EOF
        If tbl!OriginalHireDate = tbl!EffectiveDate Then
          orghrdt = tbl!EffectiveDate
        Else
          intNumDays = CInt(DateValue(tbl!EffectiveDate) - orghrdt)

        End If
        .MoveNext
      Loop
  End With

End Sub
```

This is the whole function code, hopefully this makes better sense.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly always make sure that you check the number of records to ensure that there is at least one before calling the MoveFirst method and iterating a recordset. It's better practice than relying on an error handler.

When you say that you want the number of days between the first two dates, are you referring to the dates in column "Date" in rows 0 and 1 or are you referring to dates in the same row in other columns that we can't see in the image? I assume that there are other date columns "OriginalHireDate" and "EffectiveDate".

Use the DateDiff function in VB6 to calculate the difference between dates. It's outlined here:

http://www.chennaiiq.com/developers/reference/visual_basic/functions/datediff.asp

```
intNumDays = DateDiff("d", CDate(tbl!EffectiveDate), orghrdt)
```

This will return the number of days between tbl!EffectiveDate and orghrdt. It will return a positive number if the latter is after the former and a negative number if the former is after the latter.

If you could clarify your table structure and my previous queries, I'll see whether I can help you further. You should be able to achieve what you what without the need to iterate through the whole recordset.

Comment: Thanks for the response @GuruJosh, In this case there will always be a record at least one. The dates from the image are just an example. We could have Hired and Termed a particular individual 11 times. Giving us a total of 23 records (a hire date and a term date for each time, as well as the most current hire date). I neglected to mention all of these employees are currently employed. The name originalhiredate and effectivedate what the columns are called. OriginalHireDate is always the first date in the EffectiveDate column, so it's housed both places.

Comment: I'm confused. The recordset above does not have any of the 3 columns that are referenced in the SELECT section of your query. And as Don George says, I don't believe that the word "Date" is a legal column name.

Comment: In relation to the number of records, even if you believe that there will always be records, it is still good practice to check for records. Using "On Error Resume Next" is poor programming practice in this instance. If an error of any sort were to occur then your function is going to capture data in error. Far better to anticipate any potential errors through programme logic and capture any others with an error handler, alerting the user (and yourself during testing) that an error has occurred and not allowing the application to proceed and return incorrect data.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Employees.[Employee No], Employees.Action, Employees.DDate AS Start, Min(IIf([employees_1].[DDate]>=[employees].[ddate],[employees_1].[ddate])) AS [End], IIf([end] Is Not Null,[end],Now())-[start] AS Days
FROM Employees LEFT JOIN Employees AS Employees_1 ON Employees.[Employee No] = Employees_1.[Employee No]
WHERE (((Employees_1.Action)="term"))
GROUP BY Employees.[Employee No], Employees.Action, Employees.DDate
HAVING (((Employees.Action)="hire" Or (Employees.Action)="rehire"));
```

This query gives a list of all the hire events and the corresponding terms, with the days calculated for each.  You can use a second query to sum the days by employee after you see how the 1st query turns out.

Note - this assumes that you have an alternating set of hire / termination events.  If not, you may want to add some validations for this.  Also, I think Date is reserved so I used DDate as the field name.

Comment: I need to be able do this programmically in VBA not with a query because the original data in not housed in my access database, but is a seperate SQL database.

Comment: Can't you attach the SQL table as a table in your db and then use the query?  Or convert the logic above to a SQL statement in your VBA script?